# How to model slice shaped circular wedge?

Tags: modeling, objects, bevel

I tried with bevel, but I can only do one side of the object. Do you have idea how to make whole object?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use your geometrical pattern as background blueprint, then:

- Create a circle, extrude inwards (as suggested by the other answers, the Spin or Screw tools might be more convenient ways to create the initial shape):

[image]

- Only keep a segment and delete its inner faces:

[image]
[image]

- Extrude upwards, don't forget to recalculate the normals:

[image]

- Give it thickness with the Solidify modifier (enable the Even Thickness option), or <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to Extrude along Normals and enable the Offset Even option in the Operator box:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is a most helpful way. I made whole object from full circle...

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to Moonboots' nice answer.

For precise angles (38,012 in this case), you can use the *Screw Modifier*.
Following steps are the same as in his answer (*extrude and solidify*).

[image]

Comment: yes you're right, Screw or Spin might be better to begin with  ;)

Answer (score 2):

This method that I used to create this shape might not be the best but it works at least 
First add a plane, change the size of it and rotate it 90 degree ( on Y axis in my case ) 
[image: Plane]

Now go to edit mode, select Spin tool and change the settings how ever you want: 
[image: Spin tool]

the higher the steps are, the smother it gets
[image: Spin tool settings]
now you can back to object mode, duplicate you object and change it (you can set the origin point in the middle of the object so its easier) : 
[image: duplicate] 
[image: make changes]

now you can add boolean modifier to your first object and select your second object with the eye droper tool 
[image: Boolean modifire]

And there you go, I forgot to take a picture of it but I hope it helped!

Comment: Every solution that gets you there is a good one :).